# Poor Performance of Entity Framework over simple queries using Postgresql

Tags: entity-framework, postgresql-performance, ef-postgresql

In my new project I am keen to use .NET Entity Framework on Postgresql. So I first compared the performance of Entity Framework with simple SQL query. For this I developed a sample desktop application and ran it in both the modes, viz. with Entity Framework & with simple SQL query, in multi-threaded environment. I found that the performance of Entity Framework is 50% lower than that of SQL call. I am using NPGSQL for both the cases.

Performance is the critical success factor for my application and it is serving approximately 250-300 requests per second.

Please suggest whether I should go for Entity Framework or not. Or is there any tips and tricks for improving performance of EF to inline with simple SQL Calls. I am using .NET Framework 4.5.

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info and edit your PostgreSQL version, `explain analyze` results, exact query text, etc into the question. Comment here when you're done.

Comment: There is no issue in PostgreSQl performance. In our experiment also we got better performance with SQL calls than with the Entity Framework. PostgreSQL version is 9.2.3.

Comment: OK... so what's different, then? Are the queries different? It's kind of hard to tell if you don't show the queries..

Comment: use an ORM (whatever it might be) when performance is the "Key point" looks like a nonsense. It's much (much) better for maintenability purposes, not for performance.

Comment: @Raphaël Although I gave +1 to your comment I don't think it is _much (much) better for maintenability_ because when thinks don't work as expected you must deal with a thick and opaque layer of software between you and the DB.

Answer (score 0):

In general, my experience is that there is a significant performance cost to moving away from hand-tuned SQL.  The reason is that entity frameworks often don't have access to the understanding regarding what you really need or want.  If performance is critical, there may still be some use cases for ORMs  but in general you really need to be able to drop to SQL any time you are doing something beyond the simplest queries.